# How does Google Analytics record sessions of Safari that emulate Internet Explorer?

Tags: google-analytics, browser-detecting

I know there's an option in Safari that lets it seem like you're using Internet Explorer ([see here](http://www.imore.com/how-view-websites-your-mac-require-internet-explorer-or-pc)). But I am curious as to how this browser is then tracked by Google Analytics- so for example, if I am looking at sessions across browsers, would this show up under Safari or Internet Explorer?

I tried to find something in the Google analytics documentation that might answer this, but couldn't.

Edit: It seems that this method doesn't really let Safari emulate IE, rather it just tells the site that's being visited that the browser is IE and not Safari: http://www.davidalison.com/2008/05/how-to-let-safari-pretend-its-ie.html

In this case, I think Google Analytics would record the sessions as IE sessions, but I'd be interested to hear if anyone can contradict this conclusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this method doesn't really let Safari emulate IE, rather it just tells the site that's being visited that the browser is IE and not Safari: http://www.davidalison.com/2008/05/how-to-let-safari-pretend-its-ie.html

In this case, I think it's safe to assume that Google Analytics would record the sessions as IE sessions.